# Can not copy SQL Server files, Access is denied

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need to copy my SQL Server DBs to a folder. The files are attached to SQL Server, which I have detached using my code. When I try to copy these files using

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(filePathToCopyFrom1, targetFilePath1)
```

It returns error:
"Access to the folder D:\MyDbs is denied"

When I manually coped these files, it asked "You need Administror permission to copy these files"  I clicked continue and it worked but how to fix this using my vb.net code?

I have given Full Control to administrator from Windows but still it did not work.
Thanks

Comment: What user is your code running as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the detaching process went well. You can copy through windows explorer, but not from you application. The key difference here is that the files are protected to be accessed by the administrator user only.

Then, you need to run your application using an administrator windows account so that the application inherits the permissions of the user to be able to perform this operation.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, if you are using Windows Vista+ (which I assume you do) the root folder is almost off limits. You can run the App as Administrator, or copy it to a folder in the root. The other point is that where you copy from. If the DB is currently in Program files, it is very possible that you will get this problem as well, and then you will have to run the application as Administrator.

Right click on the application, and select Run as Administrator, or select properties and in Compatibility check the box that the program should be running as Administrator. If you use the latter, then a box will pop up every time you run it, unless you change the User Account Control settings.